# Designing own Result/Either: Should Success type and Error type always be destinct?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, rvalue-reference

I have an implementation of `Result`/`Either` for c++. The class features following [type-converting constructor](https://github.com/abbyssoul/libsolace/blob/master/include/solace/result.hpp#L300):

```cpp
template <typename V, typename E>
class Result {
...
    template<typename X>
    constexpr Result(X&& value);
...
};
```

The purpose of this is to enable code like this:

```cpp
Result<SomeType, int> value = SomeType{...};
EXPECT_TRUE(result.isOk());   // TRUE

// Also
Result<SomeType, int> value = 10;
EXPECT_TRUE(result.isError());   // TRUE
```

This is important for function returning values:

```cpp
Result<SuccessType, int> func() {
  SuccessType result{...};
...
  return result;
}
...

EXPECT_TRUE(func().isOk());
```

Now it turned out that such constructor is too permissive and leads to undesirable type conversion.s I'd like to constrain it.

So the questions are:
 - Do you think it is useful to allow same-types for Value result and Error? For example: 
`Result<MyTypeA, MyTypeA> r{};` Do you have an example when error-type and success types are the same and it is useful?

The motivation for this question is the fact that I can get rid of template<> constructor but only if V and E are not the same types:

```cpp
template<class V, class E>
struct Result {
    constexpr result(V&& value);    
    constexpr result(E&& value);
...
```

- Also, do you think having r-value only constructor is sufficient in practice?
  I can't think of Result<> not being return value - and thus no point in not moving value out of intermediate object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a **symmetric** either you want to convert from either type implicitly.  If you are passed something that can convert to both, you want to fail.

If you are an **asymmetric** either, like a result, you want to implicitly convert from the *favored* type.  From the disfavored type, you want to only convert explicitly.

```
template<class X>
struct Error {
  X x;
};

template<class V, class E>
struct Result {
  Result( V&& v );
  Result( Error<E> e );
  // or even:
  template<class O,
    std::enable_if_t< std::is_convertible_v<O, E>, bool > = true
  >
  Result( Error<O> e );
};
```

Use looks like:

```
Result<SomeType, int> value = SomeType{...};
EXPECT_TRUE(result.isOk());   // TRUE

// Also
Result<SomeType, int> value = Error{10};
EXPECT_TRUE(result.isError());   // TRUE
```

And:

```
Result<SuccessType, int> func() {
  SuccessType result{...};
...
  return result;
}
```

works, as does:

```
Result<SuccessType, int> func() {
  return Error{10};
}
```

implicit converting-to error state should be avoided, it is far too easy to access accidentally.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually do have an equivalent of `template<> Error` from your example to [shuttle values](https://github.com/abbyssoul/libsolace/blob/master/include/solace/result.hpp#L66) with Prefered/Unexpected meaning.
And correcponding [constructors](https://github.com/abbyssoul/libsolace/blob/master/include/solace/result.hpp#L247).

I was more concerned with getting rid of temp object where possible by going to direct convertion: `PreferredType -> Restult<PreferredType, Error>` for functions returning `PreferredType`.